# How can I reduce the amount of rows in a SQLite query?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two columns i want data from but when i use:

```
SELECT rank, points FROM game
```

I get everything like this:

```
Rank | Points

rank_1 | 10
rank_2 | 5
rank_3 | 20
rank_1 | 5
rank_1 | 6
rank_2 | 4
```

I can't figure out how to group all with the same rank into just one row and also group all the individuals points into one row.
Like this:

```
Rank | Points

rank_1 | 21
rank_2 | 9
rank_3 | 20
```

So i can see which rank has the most points collectively.

Comment: It would help to learn some SQL when you attempt to use an SQL based database in your code. You can for example check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp, You might even guess that it is a SUM() operation GROUPed BY rank column.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very basic `GROUP BY` with a `SUM()`:

```
Select Rank, Sum(Points) As Points
From Game
Group by Rank
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rank, SUM(points) FROM game GROUP BY rank
```

Comment: Thank you! Was exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select [rank], sum(points) as points
from game
group by [rank]
order by sum(points) desc;
```